# Why does calling a visualforce page with an Id parameter transform to a long string of characters?

Tags: visualforce

I am invoking a vf page from a button and I was hoping to get the id from the url parameter. However the value comes to the vf page as a long string of characters. What can I do to get the value passed?

Button or Link URL  /apex/SendInvoiceEmailLWCPage?id={!AVAB__SO_Document__c.Id} becomes

https://***.lightning.force.com/one/one.app#eyJjb21wb25lbnREZWYiOiJvbmU6YWxvaGFQYWdlIiwiYXR0cmlidXRlcyI6eyJhZGRyZXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9jdXN0b21lcmRvbWFpbi0tbXJhY2NvdXRnLmxpZ2h0bmluZy5mb3JjZS5jb20vYXBleC9TZW5kSW52b2ljZUVtYWlsTFdDUGFnZT9pZD1hMkQwbTAwMDAwMlBkVUUifSwic3RhdGUiOnt9fQ%3D%3D

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in Lightning Experience.  Visualforce pages run in iframes in Lightning, so they cannot access the parent URL.  See the [Visualforce and Lightning Experience Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/lex_dev_visualforce/lex_dev_visualforce_container).

Comment: Awesome! You are absolutely right! After switching to classic I get this..https://***.c.visualforce.com/apex/SendInvoiceEmailLWCPage?id=a2D0m000002PdUE

Comment: Thanks! @David.